# Issue with Spring Security SAML hitting infinite redirect behind a load balancer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, saml

I am having trouble with using the spring security saml extension with my spring boot application. We use ping federate and had a saml application set up. It was set up with a localhost:8443/saml/SSO url and another one for test inside my aws cluster. It looked something like this domain.com/saml/SSO.

My aws is an ECS Application Service fronted with a load balancer using port 443 only all the way through.

When I ran this locally the redirect was working great and no issues what so ever. I used this as a reference implementation https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vdenotaris/spring/boot/security/saml/web/config/WebSecurityConfig.java

Then when I deployed it to our aws instance it wouldn't work all of a sudden. It seemed to be getting an infinite amount of success redirects. When I looked at the SAML Trace it seems that the AssertionConsumerServiceURL is using the ECS Services ip address and port instead of the load blancers.

I then discovered that there is a configuration bean for handling the load balancer support. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-advanced.html

I tried implementing that and it seemed nothing changed. The assertionConsumerServiceUrl was still using the ip address and running an infinite redirect on success.

I am not sure if I am configuring the load balancer bean correctly or if there is something else I could do to figure this out.

Here is a sample of the WebSecurityConfig.java

```
package com.test.config;

import com.test.core.SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.ContainerBasedAuthenticationFilter;
import org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider;
import org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProvider;
import org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException;
import org.opensaml.xml.parse.ParserPool;
import org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.saml.*;
import org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProvider;
import org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl;
import org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderLB;
import org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager;
import org.springframework.security.saml.key.KeyManager;
import org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger;
import org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.*;
import org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder;
import org.springframework.security.saml.processor.*;
import org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.*;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import java.util.*;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 15)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {

    private Timer backgroundTaskTimer;
    private MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager;

    public void init() {
        this.backgroundTaskTimer = new Timer(true);
        this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        this.backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
        this.backgroundTaskTimer.cancel();
        this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.shutdown();
    }

    @Value("${security.saml2.metadata-url}")
    String metadataUrl;

    @Value("${security.saml2.entity-id}")
    String entityId;

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-store}")
    String keyStore;

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-store-password}")
    String keyStorePassword;

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-alias}")
    String keyAlias;

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-password}")
    String keyPassword;

    @Autowired
    private SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl samlUserDetailsServiceImpl;

    // Initialization of the velocity engine
    @Bean
    public VelocityEngine velocityEngine() {
        return VelocityFactory.getEngine();
    }

    // XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing
    @Bean(initMethod = "initialize")
    public StaticBasicParserPool parserPool() {
        return new StaticBasicParserPool();
    }

    @Bean(name = "parserPoolHolder")
    public ParserPoolHolder parserPoolHolder() {
        return new ParserPoolHolder();
    }

    // Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages
    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        return new HttpClient(this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager);
    }

    // SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML
    // messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
        SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider = new SAMLAuthenticationProvider();
        samlAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetails(samlUserDetailsServiceImpl);
        samlAuthenticationProvider.setForcePrincipalAsString(false);
        return samlAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    // Provider of default SAML Context
    @Bean
    public SAMLContextProviderImpl contextProvider() {
        //return new SAMLContextProviderImpl();
        SAMLContextProviderLB samlContextProviderLB = new SAMLContextProviderLB();
        samlContextProviderLB.setServerName("mydomain.zone"); // SCRUBBED MY LOAD BALANCER
        samlContextProviderLB.setScheme("https");
        samlContextProviderLB.setServerPort(443);
        samlContextProviderLB.setIncludeServerPortInRequestURL(true);
        samlContextProviderLB.setContextPath("");
        return samlContextProviderLB;
    }

    // Initialization of OpenSAML library
    @Bean
    public static SAMLBootstrap sAMLBootstrap() {
        return new SAMLBootstrap();
    }

    // Logger for SAML messages and events
    @Bean
    public SAMLDefaultLogger samlLogger() {
        return new SAMLDefaultLogger();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumer webSSOprofileConsumer() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOprofileConsumer() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfile webSSOprofile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOProfile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 ECP profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileECPImpl ecpprofile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileECPImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public SingleLogoutProfile logoutprofile() {
        return new SingleLogoutProfileImpl();
    }

    // Central storage of cryptographic keys
    @Bean
    public KeyManager keyManager() {
        DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
        Resource storeFile = loader
                .getResource(this.keyStore);
        String storePass = this.keyStorePassword;
        Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();
        passwords.put(this.keyAlias, this.keyPassword);
        String defaultKey = this.keyAlias;
        return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileOptions defaultWebSSOProfileOptions() {
        WebSSOProfileOptions webSSOProfileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
        webSSOProfileOptions.setIncludeScoping(false);
        return webSSOProfileOptions;
    }

    // Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from
    // properties file
    @Bean
    public SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint() {
        SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint = new SAMLEntryPoint();
        samlEntryPoint.setDefaultProfileOptions(defaultWebSSOProfileOptions());
        return samlEntryPoint;
    }

    // Setup advanced info about metadata
    @Bean
    public ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata() {
        ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
        extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(false);
        extendedMetadata.setSigningAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
        extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(true);
        extendedMetadata.setEcpEnabled(true);
        return extendedMetadata;
    }

    // IDP Discovery Service
    @Bean
    public SAMLDiscovery samlIDPDiscovery() {
        SAMLDiscovery idpDiscovery = new SAMLDiscovery();
        idpDiscovery.setIdpSelectionPath("/saml/discovery");
        return idpDiscovery;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("idp-ssocircle")
    public ExtendedMetadataDelegate ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider()
            throws MetadataProviderException {
        String idpSSOCircleMetadataURL = this.metadataUrl;
        HTTPMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider = new HTTPMetadataProvider(
                this.backgroundTaskTimer, httpClient(), idpSSOCircleMetadataURL);
        httpMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
        ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate =
                new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(httpMetadataProvider, extendedMetadata());
        extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(true);
        extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
        backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
        return extendedMetadataDelegate;
    }

    // IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust
    // is here
    // Do no forget to call iniitalize method on providers
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("metadata")
    public CachingMetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException {
        List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<MetadataProvider>();
        providers.add(ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider());
        return new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
    }

    // Filter automatically generates default SP metadata
    @Bean
    public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
        MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
        metadataGenerator.setEntityId("WMProcessEngineUi-203871");
        metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata());
        metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(false);
        metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager());
        return metadataGenerator;
    }

    // The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix
    // and presents SP metadata there
    @Bean
    public MetadataDisplayFilter metadataDisplayFilter() {
        return new MetadataDisplayFilter();
    }

    // Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login
    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler =
                new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/landing");
        return successRedirectHandler;
    }

    // Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler =
                new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        failureHandler.setUseForward(true);
        failureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/error");
        return failureHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter = new SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter();
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter;
    }

    // Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter() {
        return new MetadataGeneratorFilter(metadataGenerator());
    }

    // Handler for successful logout
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler() {
        SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler = new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler();
        successLogoutHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
        return successLogoutHandler;
    }

    // Logout handler terminating local session
    @Bean
    public SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler() {
        SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler =
                new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
        logoutHandler.setInvalidateHttpSession(true);
        logoutHandler.setClearAuthentication(true);
        return logoutHandler;
    }

    // Filter processing incoming logout messages
    // First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful
    // global logout
    @Bean
    public SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter samlLogoutProcessingFilter() {
        return new SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
                logoutHandler());
    }

    // Overrides default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML
    // messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLLogoutFilter samlLogoutFilter() {
        return new SAMLLogoutFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
                new LogoutHandler[]{logoutHandler()},
                new LogoutHandler[]{logoutHandler()});
    }

    // Bindings
    private ArtifactResolutionProfile artifactResolutionProfile() {
        final ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl artifactResolutionProfile =
                new ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl(httpClient());
        artifactResolutionProfile.setProcessor(new SAMLProcessorImpl(soapBinding()));
        return artifactResolutionProfile;
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPArtifactBinding artifactBinding(ParserPool parserPool, VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
        return new HTTPArtifactBinding(parserPool, velocityEngine, artifactResolutionProfile());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding soapBinding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPPostBinding httpPostBinding() {
        return new HTTPPostBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding httpRedirectDeflateBinding() {
        return new HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding httpSOAP11Binding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPPAOS11Binding httpPAOS11Binding() {
        return new HTTPPAOS11Binding(parserPool());
    }

    // Processor
    @Bean
    public SAMLProcessorImpl processor() {
        Collection<SAMLBinding> bindings = new ArrayList<SAMLBinding>();
        bindings.add(httpRedirectDeflateBinding());
        bindings.add(httpPostBinding());
        bindings.add(artifactBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine()));
        bindings.add(httpSOAP11Binding());
        bindings.add(httpPAOS11Binding());
        return new SAMLProcessorImpl(bindings);
    }

    /**
     * Define the security filter chain in order to support SSO Auth by using SAML 2.0
     *
     * @return Filter chain proxy
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean
    public FilterChainProxy samlFilter() throws Exception {
        List<SecurityFilterChain> chains = new ArrayList<SecurityFilterChain>();
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/login/**"),
                samlEntryPoint()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout/**"),
                samlLogoutFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/metadata/**"),
                metadataDisplayFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"),
                samlWebSSOProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSOHoK/**"),
                samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SingleLogout/**"),
                samlLogoutProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/discovery/**"),
                samlIDPDiscovery()));
        return new FilterChainProxy(chains);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the authentication manager currently used by Spring.
     * It represents a bean definition with the aim allow wiring from
     * other classes performing the Inversion of Control (IoC).
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    /**
     * Defines the web based security configuration.
     *
     * @param http It allows configuring web based security for specific http requests.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable();
        http
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());
        http
                .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(samlFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http
                .logout()
                .disable();    // The logout procedure is already handled by SAML filters.
    }

    /**
     * Sets a custom authentication provider.
     *
     * @param auth SecurityBuilder used to create an AuthenticationManager.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        shutdown();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean containerBasedAuthenticationFilter() {

        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistration.setFilter(new ContainerBasedAuthenticationFilter());
        filterRegistration.setInitParameters(Collections.singletonMap("authentication-provider", "com.example.webapp.SpringSecurityAuthenticationProvider")); // SCRUBBED
        filterRegistration.setOrder(101); // make sure the filter is registered after the Spring Security Filter Chain
        filterRegistration.addUrlPatterns("/app/*");
        return filterRegistration;
    }

}
```

Here is what the log looks like when it runs an infinite loop.

```
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-03-22 15:21:44.590  INFO 8 --- [-nio-443-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-03-22 15:21:44.600  INFO 8 --- [-nio-443-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 10 ms
2020-03-22 15:21:44.614  INFO 8 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] o.s.s.s.m.MetadataGeneratorFilter        : No default metadata configured, generating with default values, please pre-configure metadata for production use
2020-03-22 15:21:44.615  WARN 8 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] o.s.s.s.m.MetadataGeneratorFilter        : Generated default entity base URL https://WW.WWW.WWW.WWW:32827 based on values in the first server request. Please set property entityBaseURL on MetadataGenerator bean to fixate the value.
2020-03-22 15:21:44.767  INFO 8 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] o.s.s.s.m.MetadataGeneratorFilter        : Created default metadata for system with entityID: WMProcessEngineUi-203871
2020-03-22 15:21:45.113  INFO 8 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;XX.XXX.XXX.XX;WMProcessEngineUi-203871;https://ssobeta.domain.com;;;
2020-03-22 15:21:45.113  INFO 8 --- [-nio-443-exec-7] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;YY.YYY.YYY.YYY;WMProcessEngineUi-203871;https://ssobeta.domain.com;;;
2020-03-22 15:21:45.113  INFO 8 --- [-nio-443-exec-9] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;ZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ;WMProcessEngineUi-203871;https://ssobeta.domain.com;;;
2020-03-22 15:21:59.611  INFO 8 --- [-nio-443-exec-3] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;ZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ;WMProcessEngineUi-203871;https://ssobeta.domain.com;;;
2020-03-22 15:21:59.661  INFO 8 --- [-nio-443-exec-5] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;YY.YYY.YYY.YYY;WMProcessEngineUi-203871;https://ssobeta.domain.com;;;
```

Comment: Hi, may I know how you solved this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hey, I've exactly same issue, the saml hitting infinite redirect behind load balancer ultimately resulting in 401, @Anoopkr05 did you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: What I get after enabling logs is that Security context is cleared after successful authentication and when the redirection happens the authentication object is null in security context holder thus it redirects back to IDP, my issue is defined here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65398941/spring-boot-saml-2-authentication-object-null

Comment: For me, the issue was just an incorrect ACS url